# How to test floats results with doctest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, floating-point, doctest

I'm developing a program that makes some floating points calculations.
Is there any way to test my functions (which deliver floats) with doctests?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, just format the floats with a reasonable format, based on your knowledge of what precision you expect them to exhibit -- e.g, if you expect accuracy to 2 digits after the decimal point, you could use:

```
''' Rest of your docstring and then...

    >>> '%.2f' % funcreturningfloat()
    '123.45'

'''
```

Answer (score 11):

The following works for nosetests:

```
>>> 1/3.  # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
0.333...
```

Comment: This works for repeating decimals (because their most significant digits aren't affected by floating point error), but not in general.  For example, ">>> 1 - 10e-17" returns 0.9999999999..., which wouldn't be matched if you test for "1.0..."

Answer (score 10):

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#warnings) has a suggestion

> Floating-point numbers are also
>   subject to small output variations
>   across platforms, because Python
>   defers to the platform C library for
>   float formatting, and C libraries vary
>   widely in quality here.

```
>>> 1./7  # risky
0.14285714285714285
>>> print 1./7 # safer
0.142857142857
>>> print round(1./7, 6) # much safer
0.142857
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use numtest - a doctest extension that simplifies the test of numerical results.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numtest

```
>>> 1.0/3
0.333
```

> Failed example:
>       1.0/3 
>   Expected:
>       0.333
>   Got:
>       0.3333333333333333

```
>>> 1.0/3 # doctest: +NUMBER
0.333

import doctest
import numtest
doctest.testmod()
```

> Process finished with exit code 0

All tests passed.
No need for string formatting in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

String format allows use test tuples.

```
>>> funcreturningfloattuple(1.0)
(1.0, 1.0)
>>> '%.2f, %.2f' % funcreturningfloattuple(1.0)
'1.00, 1.00'

>>> funcreturningfloattuple(1.4)
(1.3999999999999999, 1.3999999999999999)
>>> '%.2f, %.2f' % funcreturningfloattuple(1.4)
'1.40, 1.40'
```