# Testing a "very close number" in Python with doctest

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I'm creating tests for a class using doctest. One of its functions has a random component so its output can vary. I have tried using `random.seed()` but it changes when I run the file again.

I have tried (too) to use doctest ellipsis but the number can change as the following example:

```
>>> my_function(params)
9.99
>>> my_function(params)
10.01
```

Is there a function to test "around" a number, for example using 10 in test and accepting 9.99 and 10.01 as well?

Comment: Normally you'd do something like `abs(my_function(params) - my_function(params)) < 0.01`. Some other options at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2428618/3001761.

Comment: Havent tried doctest, but in the `unittest` module, you can use the `assertAlmostEqual` function. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-unittest-assertalmostequal-function/

Comment: @RandomDavis How can I use it inside a test (in Python doctest)? I'm looking for an "ellipsis" kind of function